# How does oozie know who I am?

Tags: security, hadoop, impersonation, oozie

When I run an oozie job, it is submitted to some sort of oozie coordinator where jobs are later run as myself (or under the linux account from which I submitted the job to oozie).

Im guessing oozie can impersonate me using secure impersonation (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/Secure_Impersonation.html), but when the job is beign submitted on the commandline, what is the mechanism that tells oozie 'the user who is submitting this job is XXX'?  How secure is that mechanism?  Would oozie prevent a user from trying to submit a job as if they were another user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The details are actually added in the oozie-site.xml while configuring .

find below a sample :

```
 <property>
    <name>oozie.system.id</name>
    <value>${user.name}</value>
    <description>
        The Oozie system ID.
    </description>
  </property>
```

This actually does the impersonation.